# How to make a drop down menu from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a horizontal and vertical drop down menus whose orientation will be from right to left, instead of left to right..

Are there ready jquery/javascript/css templates/scripts that I could use to achieve my aim?

Comment: There probably are, but this isn't the place to find them.

Comment: What mark up are you using? What CSS have you tried? What problems are you having? And why, in 2012, are you considering a JavaScript-powered drop-down menu?

Comment: I've only seen drop down menus that drop downwards, not to the right... can you give an example of left to right, so we can point you in the right direction?

Comment: It's usually called a "flyout" menu, Google for that instead, and just adjust the positioning to appear on the left instead of the right. Voting to close as you are not asking a specific question, just polling for suggestions.

Comment: I am thinking of using a list. I want the as the menu item to appear to the left each time, the user hovers over every one of the items

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff online.

Have a look at
[uvumitools](http://uvumitools.com/)

Or just search yourself with key `rtl` (right to left)
i.e. drop down menus rtl

Comment: but do anyone of them show you how to build a menu bar from right to left

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Here is a clue - replace `left` with `right` and vice-versa. If you build a menu and you cannot get it to work as you want then add your code to your question and we will offer you some advice.